# unable to get the message

Tags: java

```
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
        String  Message =  dis.readUTF(); 
        History.setText(History.getText()+ '\n' + "Client:-" + Message);
        System.out.println("Message from client :- "+ Message);
        }
    catch(IOException e) {

        History.setText(History.getText()+ "\n" + "Error in Connection");
        History.setText(History.getText()+ "\n" + "Please Try Again or Exit");
```

Solved 
Now able to get output from the client and the user

Comment: For starters I would add logging in IOException catching blocks. Maybe an exception is being thrown somewhere. Another observation - the DataInputStreams and DataOutputStreams are not being closed. You could use try-with resources for that.

Comment: What does "they are _not able_ to receive and send the message from each other" mean? Exception is thrown or server and client start waiting and nothing happens?

Comment: server and client successfully connects but neither client nor server is able to receive the message from each other when I click on send button.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that both the Client and Server are waiting for one to send a message to the other. Your code structure states that after the connection is made, the Server waits for a message from the Client,

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
String  Message =  dis.readUTF(); 
History.setText(History.getText()+ '\n' + "Client:-" + Message);
System.out.println("Message from client :- "+ Message);
```

And your Client is also waiting for a message from the Server,

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
String  Message =  dis.readUTF();
History.setText(History.getText()+ '\n' + "Server:- " + Message);
```

Remove either of those lines of code or have either the Client or the Server send a message to the other before waiting for an incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.

In the action handler, you are clearing the Msg before sending it.

```
Msg.setText("");
```

Remove that line in the client and the server.

You still have problems, because only the first message can be received.